# XFBML Send Invitation Preview Dialog Box got cut off by iframe size

Tags: facebook, popup, xfbml, invitation

i been stressed with this thing all day. so i made a invitation apps on my facebook fans page, to get people suggest or invite to their fans about my fan page.

my xfbml code are like this

```
<div id="fb-root" style="overflow:auto;">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({
appId  : '2071839326xxxxx',
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
</script>

<fb:serverFbml width="520">
<script type="text/fbml">

<fb:request-form
action="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Nikolius-Web-Development-Tutorial/190882787595987"
method="POST"
invite="true"
type="Nikolius-Web"
content="Undang Temen bergabung di Nikolius-Web <fb:req-choice url='http://www.facebook.com/pages/Nikolius-Web-Development-Tutorial/190882787595987'  label='Go' />"
>

<fb:multi-friend-selector actiontext="Undang Temen bergabung di Nikolius-Web" rows="3" cols="3" showborder="true" />
</fb:request-form>

</script>
</fb:serverFbml>
</div>
```

the problem is when i click the send invitation button, and a dialog confirmation comes up. the dialog box got cut off in the right side like in this picture
[image]

any ideas how to resolved this problem. when i see the [manchester united fan page](http://www.facebook.com/manchesterunited?sk=app_10442206389) that have the same apps, the dialog box just show normaly. already tried this whole day but still struggle to get this right. :(

sorry for my english. hope you guys know what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

FBML is being deprecated very soon.  I would suggest rewriting your app using the latest Facebook APIs.  It's possible that the latest dialogs don't crop while shown as a page tab app.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the width in tag  `fb:serverFbml` `width="520"` to `fb:serverFbml width="420"` that will be work as required.